# IOS : Call a Method From Block

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.3

Actually ,I've been looking around at how to call a method from a block.
I am trying to fetch all images from iphone photo app .Here is the code....

```
void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)   
     if(group != nil) {
        [self.groups addObject:group];
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:selectionBlock];
    }
};

[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:groupTypes
                  usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {NSLog(@"A problem occurred");}];
```

In selectionBlock ... I just want to add an action when user click on any image.
so I tried this code ..

```
[imgView addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

buttonPressed is also defined in the same .m file.

```
- (void) buttonPressed: (id) sender {
UIAlertView* av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Howdy!"
                                             message:@"You tapped me."
                                            delegate:nil
                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Cool"
                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
[av show];
}
```

But in selectionBlock I am getting "No visible @interface for 'UIImageView' declares the selector 'addTarget:action:forControlEvents' "

I am new to iOS programming. so any help would be very, very appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` is a method on `UIControl`. `UIButton`, `UISwitch`, and so on are all subclasses of `UIControl`. `UIImageView`, however, is not, so it does not respond to that selector. Since your `imgView` variable is a `UIImageView`, the compiler won't let you call this method on it. This has nothing to do with calling it in from a block, btw - but only with what methods objects declare they respond to.

Hope this helps!

Comment: so what should I do now ?? ... Should I put this imgView inside UIButton and then add this action ?? I just want these imgView clickable so that I can get its url in buttonPressed method.

Comment: What I'd do is take your button and call `setImage:forState:` or `setBackgroundImage:forState:` and passing for the `UIImage` argument the image you were displaying in your image view.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
[imgView addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

to:

```
[imgView addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

(with the colon ":" character)

Because buttonPressed has an argument.

Comment: Yeah -buttonPressed: has an argument, but UIImageView still doesn't implement target-action paradigm, so this is not an answer.